# Show that following subset of $\mathbb R^2$ is compact

Tags: compactness, proof-verification

> Show that following subset of $\mathbb R^2$ is compact: $$\{(x, y) : x^{2/3}+y^{2/3} = 1\}$$

My attempt:

$A=\{(x, y) : x^{2}+y^{2} = 1\}$ is compact, $f:(x,y)\mapsto(x^{1/3},y^{1/3})$ is continuous and $f(A)=\{(x, y) : x^{2/3}+y^{2/3} = 1\}.$ So $f(A)$ is compact.

Am I correct?

Comment: No, $(\sqrt{1/2}, \sqrt{1/2}) \in A$ but $(\sqrt{1/2}^{1/3})^{2/3}+(\sqrt{1/2}^{1/3})^{2/3} \neq 1$. Anyhow: how do you know that $A$ is compact? If you proved that already you should be able to prove the claim.

Comment: You can take the derivative with respect to $x$, set $y' = 0$ and solve for the min/max.  The same min/max applies to $y$ since the equation is symmetric.  This shows that it's bounded.  Now you only have to show that the set is closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, $(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2},\frac{1}{\sqrt 2})\in A$ but $f(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2},\frac{1}{\sqrt 2})$ isn't in the given set.

Notice that the given set is $g^{-1}(1)$ where
$$g:(x,y)\mapsto x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}$$ so it's a closed set of $\mathbb R^2$ and the bounded set $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$ contains the given set so it's also bounded. Conclude.

Comment: Very nice, Sami!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in a somewhat poetic style, if we define function $F(x,y)=x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}-1$ this function is obviously differentiable so the set $F(x,y)=0$ is a differentiable curve in $\mathbb R^2$. Complement of differentiable curve is "obviously" open set so the curve is closed. It is also bounded because if we assume that there is point on the curve whose either coordinate is greater than $1$ you arrive at the contradiction so it is closed and bounded so it is compact.

To add: I do not know if all these steps are approved, because I do not know about theorem that says that the set of zeroes of differentiable function $F(x,y)$ is a differentiable curve if the set does not consist of isolated points and that the complement of the differentiable curve in $\mathbb R^2$ is an open set, but it seems to me on the intuitive ground that it is so so i give this approach to the problem.

Comment: If $F(x, y)$ is differentiable, it's also continuous. The set where $F = 0$ is preimage of closed subset (zero is a point on $\mathbb{R}$, closed) for this continuous function, hence it's closed. So you don't need the theorem you mentioned. It's called implicit function theorem, by the way.

Comment: @Dmitry I wanted to prove it without using the fact that the preimage of the closed set under a continuous mapping is a closed set. This is alternative approach, just that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your idea is really nice. You wanted to say that our set is a continuous image of the unit circle which is a known compact set and being the continuous image of a compact set our set will be compact. Good idea.. But the choice of the map $f$ was unfortunately not the suitable one.. You can in fact intuitively think if u take the cube roots of 2 numbers and take the sum it is not in general sum of those two numbers..!(Your setup requires both the sums to be equal to 1!) Try to draw the curve using Geogebra or some softwares like that and see if it is possible at all to get our set as a continuous image of the unit circle. That would be a nice exercise..:D We can of course prove the compactness by using Heine Borel theorem. But I think that's not what you want..:)

Answer (score 0):

Draw the graph, We get an asteroid. It is obvious that set is closed and bounded. So, the given set is compact.[image]